# Compare two API test runs in Postman

Tags: postman

Is it possible to compare the results of API test runs (versions) in Postman? Or is it only possible when integrated with i.g. AzDO or Jenkins?

Answer (score 0):

It can be over viewed with post requests  in the Body part after making a get request. (format can be raw or none)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however I am looking for something automated here. For example, I want to get the result of automated comparison of the contents in API calls in two different test runs.